# Do I interpret this notation correctly?

Tags: functions

I am working on code where I need to create a function that can use 4 points (2 normal points and 2 control points) to calculate a bezier curve.

I am using Khan academy to get a better knowledge of mathematics for these kind of situations but I am not yet at a good enough point to understand everything yet I think, or at least I am doubting myself.

I don't think the matehematics are very difficult but it is more the notation that confuses me. Especially because for example multiply signs are generally left out, but how do I know where to use them or where not.

A lot of times I find a good example of a calculation/algorithm on wikipedia, but most of the time the notation still confuses me too much to confidently work with it.

I think when I have a good example of how to read one notation then it will be a lot easier to figure out the rest too.

Right now I am looking at this wikipeda page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

One of the notations that confuse me is the following:
This can be found on wikipedia below Cubic Bézier curves->The explicit form of the curve

```
[Cubic Bezier Curve notation][1]
```

What I find hard to grasp is, first, what is "t"?
Is "t" like the position between P0 and P3 on the line? Like is "t" always between 0 and 1 and 0.5 is a point in the middle of the bezier curve?
That is what it means at the end right? 0 < t < 1 that it is always between 0 and 1?

Where do I add multiply signs exactly?

Also some notation have [] characters, what do they imply?

If I would want to calculate the middle of the bezier curve, for example 0.5, how would I write this out?

I would expect something like this (Where P0, P1, P2 and P3 are 2D vectors) and "t" can only be equal to or between 0 and 1 also including multiply signs:

```
B(0.5) = (1-0.5)³*P0+3*(1-0.5)²*0.5*P1+3(1-0.5)*0.5²*P2+0.5³*P3
```

Would that be correct? Or am I missing something? And would B(t) return a 2d vector?

Because I tried to do this in code (C# Unity) like this, but I don't get the values I would expect.

```
private Vector2 CalculateBezierCurve( Vector2 P0, Vector2 P1, Vector2 P2, Vector2 P3, float posOnCurve )
{        
    return (Mathf.Pow((1.0f - posOnCurve), 3) * P0 + 3 * Mathf.Pow((1 - posOnCurve), 2) * posOnCurve * P1 + 3 * (1 - posOnCurve) * Mathf.Pow(posOnCurve, 2) * P2 + Mathf.Pow(posOnCurve, 3) * P3);
}
```

EDIT: Actually I made a mistake, not in the function but in the code before the function. So I understood the notation correctly and this function is working as intended. Sorry about that!

Comment: I recommend moving this question to stackoverflow.

Comment: "A Bézier curve is a *parametric* curve" and $t$ is the parameter. The formula is a polynomial wuth parameter $t$ and it ranges from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: If you input $0$ for $t$ in formula $B(t)$ you will find the output $P_0$ and with input $1$ you will find $P_n$.

Comment: Maybe "notation" instead of "notification" ?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the comments, yes I meant notation instead of notification. Sorry about that. I just found out that my implementation is actually working I was just so stupid to make a mistake in the input I send to the function. But the function itself is working fine.... Sorry!